# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error after split operation on string

Tags: java, string

I am very confused with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` I am getting. I can't make an array `TempCity`'s values allocated after  using split method.

```
String[] TempCity  = new String[2];
cityNames = props.getProperty("city.names").split(",");
cities = new City  [cityNames.length]; 
//I have also tried String[] TempCity without succes


    for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {

                     System.out.println(TempCity[1]);     //OK
                     TempCity  = cityNames[i].split(":"); // returns String array, problem is when Strings look like "something:" and do not receive second value of array
                     System.out.println(TempCity[1]);     //Error


                     try{

                         if (TempCity[1] == null){}

                     }
                   /* I was thinking about allocating second array's value in catch */
                     catch (Exception e)
                     {
                        TempCity[1] = new String();
                    //I'm getting Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

                     }

                        try{

                           cities[i] = new City( TempCity[0], TempCity[1] );
...
```

Thanks for help!
For now, my solution involves creating another string array:

```
             String[] temp  = new String[2];
             String[] tempCity  = new String[2];

             temp  = cityNames[i].split(":");

             for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){

                    tempCity[j] = temp[j];

             }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split()` does not return trailing empty strings. You have to allow for this in your code.
Use the two-argument version of `split()` and pass a negative number as the second argument.

From the javadoc:

> This method works as if by invoking
>   the two-argument split method with the
>   given expression and a limit argument
>   of zero. Trailing empty strings are
>   therefore not included in the
>   resulting array.

Answer (score 3):

It means that `split()` returned an array with a single element, and you're trying to access a second one. Evaluating `TempCity.length` will show you that it's '1'

Print out `TempCity[0]` and see what that is; it's going to be your entire input string (cityNames[i]).

Answer (score 0):

Doing `String[] TempCity  = new String[2];` does not help if you are going to overwrite `TempCity` with something else.