# Java - Trouble reading CSV to Array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I'm trying to read a .csv file to an array, and then parse the row on commas, to pull out specific numbers from my file. I'm not getting any errors, and the program runs fine, however it won't let me pull from anything other than thisLine[0]. There should be 3 elements in the line.

The csv looks something like this:

```
32.34553,-122.4535636,-118.1
32.34553,-122.4535536,-118.1
32.34553,-122.4512236,-118.1
32.34553,-122.4515466,-118.1
32.34553,-122.4532336,-118.1
```

When I try to call `thisLine[1]` (which should be something like '-122.4535636') I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.mkyong.util.ReadCSV.run(ReadCSV.java:32)
    at com.mkyong.util.ReadCSV.main(ReadCSV.java:14)
```

I'm really new to Java so I'm sorry if this is a simple fix. Thanks for any help,

```
package com.mkyong.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadCSV obj = new ReadCSV();
        obj.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        String csvFile = "C:/Program Files/EDX/Projects/Brisbane, CA R900/Data/GIS/meters.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String csvSplitBy = ",";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                String[] thisLine = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                System.out.println("The Current Line is: " + thisLine[0] + ", " + thisLine[1]);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br !=null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a blank line in your file?!

Comment: @Houston Your code runs fine for me with no issues. The println for thisLine[0] and thisLine[1] prints successfully. Where is the problem. In which other place are you trying to call thisLine[1]?

Comment: I did have a blank line at the end, but I deleted it and it still does the same thing.

Comment: @vinay I'm not calling it anywhere else. Must be a problem with the .csv

Comment: Yeah, the source with the provided example works fine. As said by @ericbn probably is an empty line, or a line with only one column. Update the question with the part where the error occurs.

Comment: It was the first line. it only contained "'5',," which seems like it should still have a second element of "", but I guess not. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is with the CSV file. Open it with Microsoft excel and check if it has 4 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error after split operation on string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758875/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-error-after-split-operation-on-string)